# create mask of non-nan matrix intersections

Tags: python, numpy

I have two (or more) numpy arrays, in which I need to perform a calulcation on *each* cell where all matching cell positions have non-null values.

```
import numpy

arr_a = numpy.zeros(shape=(5,6))
arr_a.fill(numpy.nan)
arr_b = numpy.zeros(shape=(5,6))
arr_b.fill(numpy.nan)

arr_a[1,1] = 12.9
arr_b[1,1] = 99.2
arr_b[1,2] = 99.2
```

Sample:

```
arr_a:
array([[  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,  12.9,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan]])

arr_b:
array([[  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,  99.2,  99.2,   nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan]])
```

So with the above example, I expect only 1 cell `(1,1)` to match.

Basically, I want to do something like this:

```
results = defaultdict(list)
mask = numpy.logical_and(arr_a, arr_b)
for arr in (a, b):
    # filter out non-overlapping values
    filtered_arr = arr.apply(mask)
    for cell in numpy.nditer(filtered_arr[filtered_arr != numpy.nan]):
        result = big_calc(filtered_arr[cell])
        results[cell].append(result)
```

*still don't quite have the hang of numpy*

I tried to use `numpy.logical_and(arr_a, arr_b)` but it just seems to be returning all `True`.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: By "non-null", do you mean non-nan?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html).

Comment: yes non-not-a-number (nan), sorry been doing a lot of database work recently.

Comment: Side note: instead of `zeros()` followed by `fill()`, you should use NumPy 1.8's `full()`, or if using an older version of NumPy, you should replace `zeros()` by `empty()`: not only is it faster, but it also signals to the readers of your code that you don't care about the array being filled with zeros (which makes replacing the values by something else less of a surprise).

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about `full()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test for Not Not-A-Number (not NAN):

```
from numpy import isnan
result = ~isnan(arr_a) * ~isnan(arr_b)
```

Alternatively, if you want to rule out both NANs and infinities, then run:

```
from numpy import isfinite
isfinite(arr_a) * isfinite(arr_b)
```

On your test arrays, both of the above return:

```
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

which is True only in the (1, 1) position.

Comment: I would expect the not operator to be better than the `== 0`:  `~isnan(arr_a)` rather than `isnan(arr_a) == 0`.

Comment: I would write the logical AND as `&` instead of the less explicit `*`. The execution speed is the same for both (with NumPy 1.8), but being more explicit matters: since `&` exists exactly for this purpose, it is best to use it.